# How to display different image from a server in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, cordova

How can display different img from a server with angularJS,  I have ng-repeat post in posts and for each post I want to retrieve his avatar; I thought to call a function getImage(post.author.id) and retrieve his avatar

```
  $scope.getImage=function(a){

    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://url/provawp/api/user/get_avatar/?user_id=' +  a + '&type=full'}).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        console.log("id-autore" + a);
        var img=data.avatar;
        var element = $('<div>').html(img);
        $scope.source = element.find('img').attr("src");
      return $scope.source;
        console.log("immagine" + $scope.source);

     }).
     error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

         console.log("errore avatar");
     });

    };
```

my html :

```
<ons-list-item  class="list-item-container">
      <div class="list-item-left">
        <img ng-src="{{getImage(post.author.id)}}" class="avator">
      </div>
      <div class="list-item-right">
        <div class="list-item-content">
          <div class="name">{{post.author.name}}</div>
       <!--               <div class="name" id="id-autore" >                                   {{post.author.id}}</div> -->
        <span class="desc">{{formatDate(post.date)  |  date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ons-list-item>

</ons-list>
```

I have this error:
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations

Comment: Don't think, just write code and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below:

```
<ons-list-item  class="list-item-container">
      <div class="list-item-left">
        <img ng-src="getImage(post.author.id)" class="avator">
      </div>
      <div class="list-item-right">
        <div class="list-item-content">
          <div class="name">{{post.author.name}}</div>
       <!--               <div class="name" id="id-autore" >                                   {{post.author.id}}</div> -->
        <span class="desc">{{formatDate(post.date)  |  date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ons-list-item>

</ons-list>
```

Comment: It seems that doesn't call the function, why?